# How to align one object to the left, and one object in the center (of the entire row) in a single table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, row

I am looking for a way to align one object to the left, and one object in the center of a single table row. The object aligned to the center should be in the complete center of the table row, not of the space left after the first object.

Here are the relevant lines of code (at this stage it is messy- I only started today):

```
<tr align="center">

<img src="Logo.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding:5px" alt="This image cannot be displayed." align="left" style="max-width:100px"/>

<div align="center" style="width:100%"> <img src="Banner.png" style="padding:9px" alt="This image cannot be displayed." align="center" style="clear:both" /> </div>

</tr>
```

So how it currently appears, the first object (aligned left) appears left, right where I want it. The second object (aligned center), is aligned to the REMAINING space, not the total space of the table row, which is what I am aiming for.

If anyone knows how I could achieve this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to put the `<img>` and `<div>` inside of another `<div>` then, after that, use `float: left` to the `<img>` and use the `margin-left` css attribute to adjust your layout.

Comment: for valid html: `td` and `th` are the only elements permitted inside a `tr` element [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)

Comment: BTW. to avoid elements pushing each other around, you can use `position: absolute`. [jsfiddle.net/23ny7](http://jsfiddle.net/23ny7/)

Answer (score 0):

On html:

```
<table id="myid" border=1 style="width: 100px">
    <tr> 
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> a </td>
    </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> b </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On JS (using jquery):

```
$("#myid").find("tr").each(function(){
    tds = $(this).find("td");
    tds.eq(0).attr("align","center");
    tds.eq(1).attr("align","right");
});
```

Test it here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEC5e/)